# How I can configure Conky

Tags: conky

I installed conky in ubuntu 12.10 download software center, but I ve no idea how update or upgrade and configure it with all different scripts to Conky, if I want configure conky with conky colors what can I do???. I know almost nothing of the commands in the terminal, I apreciate a lots a so simple explanation step by step. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use conky-manager.
Then you can just place all your scripts in ./conky and they will appear in your manager, you just tick enable, and it will appear on your screen.
http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice conky [Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky) for you, and one for [command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTermina)  basics.